# how to set cookie for requests built via Resteasy Client API

Tags: java, cookies, resteasy

I am working on writing integration tests against web services that are annotated with JAX-RS annotations  and secured with Spring Security. I use Resteasy Client proxy framework to generate proxies, from which I can invoke methods on to test the web services. For example, 
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).connectionTTL(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

```
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(properties.getRestWebBaseUrl());

    ProxyBuilder<UserClient> builder = target.proxyBuilder(UserClient.class);
    UserClient userClient = builder
            .defaultConsumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

How do I add a cookie to the request being constructed by Resteasy? I have tried registering a ClientRequestFilter but it does not work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Registering a ClientRequestFilter does work, as follows :

```
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(properties.getRestWebBaseUrl());
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("foo", "bar");
client.register(new CookieClientRequestFilter(cookie));
ProxyBuilder<UserClient> builder = target.proxyBuilder(UserClient.class);
UserClient userClient = builder
        .defaultConsumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

with :

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class CookieClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    private Cookie cookie;

    public CookieClientRequestFilter(Cookie cookie) {
        super();
        this.cookie = cookie;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext) throws IOException {
        List<Object> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
        cookies.add(this.cookie);
        clientRequestContext.getHeaders().put("Cookie", cookies);
    }
}
```