# Resteasy Client: @CookieParam replicates its value on every request

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a Resteasy Client Implementation with an Interface that uses @CookieParam. The first Clientrequests adds the cookie as expected, the second adds the same value again, instead of checking if it already exists and doing some kind of replacement of the value. The same does the third and so on. This never ends and the cookie gets bigger on every request.

What would be the solution if the cookie value should be added only once?

My interace of the provided server service (which is not under my controll) looks like this. I've just written it to make it possible to use Reast Easy Proxyclient in my client implementation:

```
@POST
@Path("/my-resource")
@Produces(CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF_8)
@Consumes(CustomMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF_8)
Response createResource(@CookieParam("my-cookie") String cookie, Request request);
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation of "createResource" ?

Comment: Are you responding with a `Set-Cookie` or setting the same cookie again?

Comment: to make it clear: I'm only implementing the client against the plain interface which represents the server side (which is not under my controll). I'm not doing anything on the server side. So it's deep in Rest Easy Client implementation where it gets duplicated on every request.
The interaces definition is under my controll. I just made it to make it possible to interact with the server over rest easy proxy client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the cookie only if 'my-cookie' is null. Then you will not duplicate the same cookie.

Comment: to make it clear: I'm only implementing the client against the plain interface which represents the server side (which is not under my controll). I'm not doing anything on the server side. So it's deep in Rest Easy Client implementation where it gets duplicated on every request.

Comment: In that case, you have to customize the cookies sent with requests, this might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358105/how-to-set-cookie-for-requests-built-via-resteasy-client-api

Comment: Ok, not the way I've expected to solve it but at least a working solution.